# SQL for list of winners that have won at least a specific percentage of times

Tags: php, mysql, sql, percentage

I have to setup a versus module where users can vote for Profile A or B. Each record will store 3 imporant values: the person who voted, the person that won, the person that lost.

**user**

- id_user
- name

**user_versus**

- id_versus *- primary key*
- id_user *- the one who votes*
- id_user_winner *- the winner, obviously*
- id_user_loser *- the loser*

I can calculate a user's percentage by separately executing these queries:

- $wins = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_versus WHERE id_user_winner = 6';
- $loses = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_versus WHERE id_user_loser = 6';
- $total = $wins + $loses;

So **%wins = $wins / $total**

Still, I believe that the query could be optimized into just one, and then use it as a subquery of the report query (which is the one I actually need help with). The report needs to return:

**list of users that have a win-percentage that is greater than the win-percentage of a specified user**

I have no idea on how to proceed from this point on. Any tips will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one user:

```
SELECT ifnull(wins, 0) wins, ifnull(loses,0) loses, 
       ifnull(wins, 0)+ifnull(loses,0) total, 
       ifnull(wins, 0) / ( ifnull(wins, 0)+ifnull(loses,0)) percent
FROM (
SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_versus WHERE id_user_winner = 6 ) wins,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_versus WHERE id_user_loser = 6 ) loses
) subqry
```

For all users:

```
SELECT id_user_winner AS id_user, 
       ifnull(wins, 0) wins
       ifnull(loses,0) loses
       ifnull(wins, 0)+ifnull(loses,0) total, 
       ifnull(wins, 0) / ( ifnull(wins, 0)+ifnull(loses,0)) percent
FROM (
   SELECT id_user_winner AS id_user FROM user_versus 
   UNION
   SELECT id_user_loser FROM user_versus 
) u
LEFT JOIN
FROM (
  SELECT id_user_winner, count(*) wins
  FROM user_versus 
  GROUP BY id_user_winner
) w
ON u.id_user = id_user_winner
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_user_loser, count(*) loses
  FROM user_versus 
  GROUP BY id_user_loser
) l
ON u.id_user = l.id_user_loser
```

Comment: What happens if you have a user with no losses? What happens if you have a user with no wins? I suggest you start from User and do two left joins to your inline views. Of course you'll need to watch out for users who have neither (division by zero)

Comment: @Conrad Frix thank you very much for your comment. I corrected the answer. Division by 0 is impossible, because each user retrieved by the query must always be either the winner, or the loser, or both. We divide by the sum of: win+lose, and this sum must always be > 0.

Comment: @kordirko why do I get id_user columns with NULL value as well? Trying to figure it out without success... :s